# Where/what you get yourself into

Tags: phrase-usage, phrases

a person is inquiring about another person's decision on being included in a bridesmaid thing, then he asked:

Inquirer:

> Are you sure you know **where you get yourself into** with this whole bridesmaid thing?

Or

> Are you sure you know **what did you get yourself into** with this whole bridesmaid thing?

I am watching a movie, and the #1 sentence is, I think, the closest to my ear when the inquirer said it. Upon googling, however, **''what did you get yourself into''** appeared many times. Is it possible that #1 sentence can also be used?

Comment: The second sentence is normal. I've never heard or seen the first sentence before—it's quite unnatural. Also, it should be *yourself* (one word), not *your self*.

Comment: The second example is normally used. Whether the first might be OK depends on how you heard it, but we can't evaluate that unless you can provide some example for us to hear.

Comment: Actually, I'd phrase the seconds as, `Are you sure you know what you got yourself into with this whole bridesmaid thing?` Note also "yourself" is one word.

Comment: Oh yes, typo, thx

Comment: @DrMoishePippik I'd even say the second sentence is ungrammatical as written - a subordinate clause ("what *did you get...") shouldn't be inverted.

Comment: @MaciejStachowski, do you mean the 'auxillary then pronoun' inversion? Why not, it should be coz' it's a question?

Comment: @JohnArvin the inversion occurs already in "Are you sure" - the subordinate clauses aren't questions and shouldn't be inverted. Just like you would say "Are you sure you know him?" rather than "Are you sure *do you know him?" - the inversion only applies to the main clause.

Comment: @MaciejStachowski, agreed, it may not be grammatical, but it passes for colloquial English as she is spoke. ;-)